# Why do the two table rows get so close to each other?

Tags: itext

I am creating two rows. The first row contains 0, 1, ..., 10. The second row contains a radio button beneath each number. Here is my code:

```
        for (int k=0; k<=10; k++) {
            String text = k + "";
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
            cell.setPaddingTop(5);
            table.addCell(cell);    
        }

        for (int k=0; k<=10; k++) {
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
            cell.setPaddingTop(10); 
            cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField(radiogroup, k+""));
            table.addCell(cell);        
        }
```

MyCellField is similar to what is available on this page:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/create-fields-table

The problem is that no matter what spacing I give to the second row, the produced radio buttons in the second always overlap with their respective numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a cell without any content when you do this: `cell = new PdfPCell();`

No content means: no height. You probably want to add this line:

```
cell.setFixedHeight(30);
```

This way, you are sure that the height of the cell will be sufficient to add a radio button.

In iText 5, we often use `cell.setUseAscender(true);` and `cell.setUseDescender(true);` to get a better positioning of the text. This problem is addressed in iText 7.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Thanks, again!